# How to configure Sharepoint 2010 List to filter based on parameters?

Tags: 2010

I'm looking at the following scenario.

I have a HTML Form Web part that I want to connect to a List and pass a parameter to that list.

How exactly do I configure the list? At this point it tells me that it has "No Consumer Schema"?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do? What does the HTML Form Web Part contain? Is it a form for a SharePoint list or something else?

Comment: A basic example would be sufficient. A list with a Title, and just query for Title containing the value being passed as a parameter. I couldn't get something to work.

The HTML Form web part contains only a T1 input field and it is configured to supply that parameter to the list.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your HTML Form Web Part set a Query String parameter that would then be available for a Query String Filter Web Part to send values to your other web part with.

Answer (score 0):

The "No Consumer Schema" message appears when you want to connect web parts on a page, by editing the page by clicking "edit page". If you edit the page through SharePoint Designer however, you are able to make these connections with parameters like intended. The message probably intends to inform you, that this is not possible for a consumer to edit, but rather has to be a performed by someone in a development environment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your form. You have to go in your InfoPath to Option -> Advanced form options -> Property Promotion and there you have to add your column which will be accept parameter to “The fields listed below will be available as SharePoint Web Part connection parameters”. After that you have redeploy your [enter link description here](http://tszulczewski.com/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameter-in-url-to-infopath-form/)form.